# Android HTML Placeholders

Tags: android

How would I pass a dynamic string to a HTML document to replace the different placeholders?

I.e HTML Placeholder %title% is replaced by the dynamic string for the title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark Place Holders in HTML -
**`%NAME%`** 
Then i would load my HTML:

```
String template = Utils.inputStreamToString(assets.open("html/template.html"));
```

Then i would replace all dynamics parts with what i want like this:

```
String data = template.replaceAll("%NAME%", "Alice McGee");
```

Then i would pass it to my webView!

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/html/", data, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```